# Least privileged access to Azure service principle to add or remove user in Azure AD group using Terraform automation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-service-principal

Least privileged access to Azure service principle to add or remove user from Azure AD group. We are trying to automate the process of add or remove user from Azure AD group using Terraform. What is the least privilage access we need for the service princple to be able to authenticate.

Need least privilage access to Azure service princple

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Graph API Permissions on your Service Principal to add or remove users from Azure AD Group.

- GroupMember.ReadWrite.All or Group.ReadWrite.All

More details on Application permissions are listed on following documents:

- [Add members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
- [Remove members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Hope this helps.